# Why are there so many audio output devices?

Tags: sound, devices

My system has multiple audio output devices avaible (built-in monitor speakers connected via display port, Corsair headset with USB receiver and speakers connected with aux). In my output devices, there are too many devices, for example 4 times my headset (which only one of them is working). Is there a way to hide the ones I don't use and which doesn't work? I want only my headset and aux speakers as audio output devices.

Screenshot of my devices in sound settings:

[image: Screenshot of my devices in sound settings]